# C# MongoDB deserialization of id property

Tags: c#, json, mongodb

I have a class that looks like this:

```
public class Object
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ObjectIdConverter))]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public List<Record> Records { get; set; }
}

public class Record
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ObjectIdConverter))]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, object> Values { get; set; }
}
```

I'm trying to deserialize the following json:

```
{{
  "Id": "5791fad6fcef4434d0318d69",
  "Values": {
    "Name": "some name....",
    "Account": {
      "Value": "123",
      "Name": "Test Account"
    }
  }
}}
```

With the mongodb c# driver:

```
var record = MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.BsonSerializer.Deserialize<Record>(BsonDocument.Parse(value.ToString()));
```

But I keep receiving the error: *Element 'Id' does not match any field or property of class Record.*

Any ideas as to why it won't recognize the id property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that if you change the property name to the following then the object is deserialized correctly:

```
public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the `BsonId` attribute to your Id field.

```
public class Object
{
    [BsonId]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(ObjectIdConverter))]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }

    public List<Record> Records { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. I've added the BsonId attribute to both the Object and Record classes and the same error appears

Comment: I dont get it, how is one supposed to use the deserializer when also using [BsonId]? Is that not possible? Big gotcha. This would require me to remove all [BsonId] from my objects and then do a rename of all id-fields from "Id" to "_id", and this was the reason for even using the [BsonId] from start, I don't want my id-fields to be namned _id.